# Symfony - authentication of user in test env

Tags: symfony, authentication, phpunit, symfony4

I am trying to run tests in my Symfony test environment but keep getting an error.

> ```
> Error: Call to a member function getContainer() on null
> ```

I figured I have problem with authentication of the user.

I have loaded a fixture to persist one user object into test database fort the needs of authentications (even if i do not know it that is needed).

```
protected function createAuthenticatedClient(): KernelBrowser
{
    self::ensureKernelShutdown();
    $client = static::createClient();

    $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $firewall = 'secured_area';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewall, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    return $client;
}
```

I do not know what am I doing wrong?

I have to note that my project does the authentication trough `x-api-key` value in header.

This is a whole new world in Symfony regarding tests for me, so any guidance and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `$client = whatever; $session = $this->client` Can you spot the error?

Comment: Yeah, fixed that, error still persists. @Cerad

Comment: Since symfony 5.1 there is a nice helper to mock a logged in user in tests. `$client->loginUser($testUser)`. See https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-simpler-login-in-tests.

Comment: I know. Problem is I am using version 4.4 @simon.ro

Comment: If it is the same error coming from the same line then no, you did not actually fix it.  But I and not surprised at all if you are encountering different errors.  Pretty sure your approach is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: You `get` the session 'service' from `self::$container` not, from the client, but as @Cerad points out, if it's the same error, the client is not being created. And considering your comments about your authentication mechanism, you (probably) don't need to do all that. [Pass an array as the second argument with your custom headers](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/testing.html#sending-custom-headers) when creating the client: `static::createClient([], ['x-api-key' => 'apikey']);`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But, this throws: Error: Call to undefined function App\Security\apache_request_headers() @msg

Comment: And do I need to pull that api key from my client table from test db? @msg

Comment: You can hardcode it in your tests, but it goes through the normal authentication process, so the framework does the retrieving and checking, it should just exist and be valid, but nothing else on your part (unless you want to do load it it in case you change it, but I see no point). BTW, the previous link states that you have to normalize the headers yourself, so it should be `HTTP_X_API_KEY` and not `x-api-key` as I stated. And the `apache_request_headers` thing is quite odd, as it should be the framework calling that function (if it's available at all), not any code in `App\Security`.